# wcf guaranteed asynchronous call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Is there a way to configure WCF to do guaranteed asynchronous calls (remotely - on different machine)? I.e. something you would implement using some MQ messaging mechanism before WCF era.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re clarification (comment) - you can use MSMQ as a WCF channel ;-p using the [`NetMsmqBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netmsmqbinding.aspx) and related bindings.

See [here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2008/02/28/wcf-and-msmq.aspx), for example - or for an MSDN document, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732355.aspx).

---

Well, you could enable the "Generate asynchronous operations" button in the IDE (or `svcutil /async`) - and use the async methods. In reality, the sync methods usually call the async methods internally and block on the reply.

Is there some specific problem you are seeing?